# Allow certain values to bypass a foreign key constraint on insert into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: database, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I'm using a PostgreSQL table to store a file structure and I'd like to be able to allow certain files (namely home `~`) to bypass a foreign key constraint I place on one column.

My table creation looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE files_table (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    file_name TEXT NOT NULL,
    parent integer,
    -- version_num_type is a composite type three smallints.
    -- version_list is a separate table containing valid version numbers
    version version_num_type NOT NULL REFERENCES version_list,
    -- full_path is column in this table I didn't include here that contains the
    -- complete file name, starting at root '~'
    CONSTRAINT file_unique_check UNIQUE(version, full_path)
);
```

The constraint I initially wanted to add was:

```
CONSTRAINT valid_parent_file FOREIGN KEY parent REFERENCES files_table(id);
```

And since versions are only added periodically, I could just disable this constraint using a query like this:

```
ALTER TABLE files_table DISABLE CONSTRAINT valid_parent_file;
```

And then just re-enable the constraint after I've added the new version of the table. Unfortunately though, this would require the user adding things to the table to have the ALTER TABLE permission, which seems unnecessary to me and I'd prefer to keep the production database credentials as limited as possible.

I was wondering if it was possible to allow something to bypass the constraint if it's `file_name` column was equal to `~` because the first row I'll add for every new version will be the root directory, whose parent will simply be `NULL`. It should still check for uniqueness however, so it cannot bypass **all** constraints.

Is there a way, either in defining the constraint or defining the query, that I can allow an insert to bypass the foreign key restraint on a condition?

Here's an example illustrating what I mean:

```
id     file_name     parent   version_num_type
1      ~             NULL     (1,0,0)
2      foo/          1        (1,0,0)
3      bar.txt       2        (1,0,0)
```

And then I want to be able to add:

```
id     file_name     parent   version_num_type
4      ~             NULL     (1,1,0)
```

Because even though its parent value is NULL, it's the root for a new version, so it doesn't need a parent.

But trying to insert either of these should fail:

```
id     file_name     parent   version_num_type
5      foo/          NULL     (1,1,0)
5      foo/          17       (1,1,0)
```

The first would fail because its parent is NULL and it's not the root while the second would fail because it is referencing a parent id that is not in the table yet.

Comment: Do you only want to allow a null `parent` for `file_name = '~'`? A check constraint will do that: `CHECK (file_name = '~' AND parent IS NULL OR parent IS NOT NULL)`.

Comment: @teppic I only want to allow a null parent for `file_name = '~'` but I also want to make sure that non-null parents reference primary keys that exist in the table already (like a foreign key).

Comment: null values are not considered equal, so the constraint + a unique index will do what you want.

Comment: @teppic How would that ensure the parent is also in the table? Because I also want to make sure it's referring to a parent that actually exists.

Comment: You can have a foreign key constraint on a nullable column. It will have no effect if the key is null.

Comment: @teppic Oh I think I understand what you mean! Add a foreign key constraint AND a constraint to make sure only `file_name = '~'` can be null. I'll try that, do you want to type that up as an answer?